# How an embedded board developers decided on what endianity they want to support?

Tags: embedded, endianness

ARM MCU supports both little endian and big endian. However, when the manufactures design microcontrollers i.e. when they use ARM microprocessor and add peripherals to it they support either big endian or little endian. So, my question is how board manufacturer like STM32, TI decides whether they want to support little or big endian. As far as I understand ARM microprocessor supports both little endian and big endian.

Comment: Incorrect - some of the ARMs support.

Answer (score 2):

It's completely subjective.

The terms *Big Endian* and *Little Endian* are taken from the book Gulliver's Travels, where two nations fight a fierce, bloody war based on the disagreement about if one should hatch an egg on the "big" side or the "little" side. That is, they were fighting over something completely pointless.

In the computer world in the 1970s-80s, the Big Endian camp consisted prominently of Motorola and IBM, and the Little Endian camp consisted prominently of Intel. All other manufacturers had to pick either side.

So mostly it is picked by tradition.

Regarding ARM specifically, all ARM Cortex are in practice Little Endian. Even Freescale, former Motorola, picked Little Endian for their Kinetis family. There are however various other 32 bit architectures that use Big Endian, including I believe some pre-Cortex ARMs.

Importantly, "network endianess" is almost always Big Endian, also out of tradition. But this has an actual objective and practical reason though, namely CRC calculations. In order to create a CRC calculator in pure digital logic with XOR gates, the data must be transmitted MS byte first. It is nowadays rare to implement CRC using digital gates, but that's the historical reason.

Answer (score 1):

The software ecosystem for ARM Cortex MCUs is more-or-less exclusively little-endian.  It would be unlikely that anyone would choose to use big-endian exclusively or even mixed-endian without very a good application specific reason.  So the choice is normally simple, and I doubt the designers think about it at all.

Answer (score -1):

Unlike other ARM implementations, Cortex-M MCUs do not support "on-the-fly" changing of the endianness, and the choice of endianness is fixed by the silicon vendors. All popular (and maybe even non-popular ones) Cortex-M MCUs implement little endian, so that's the practical answer.

Little endian is easier to map a stream of bytes/ASCII characters into memory. So maybe that's one reason why it is more popular.

The choice of endianness is pretty immaterial. If you are writing standalone code in a high level language that does not exchange data with anyone else, then it really does not matter which endianness you choose. Even if you have to exchange data, then usually you would encapsulate the data access in some low level functions so by and large the endianness is still not too impactful.

Comment: "Little endian is easier to map a stream of bytes/ASCII characters into memory. So maybe that's one reason why it is more popular. "  Eh? Endianess doesn't even apply to a stream of bytes, so what are you even talking about?

Comment: @Lundin: BYTE endianness. It's the NUXI problem. i.e. on an Little Endian machine, if you read the bytes in memory it reads as UNIX, but if you read the memory bytes in order on a Big Endian machine, it reads as NUXI. What do you think Endianness apply to?

Comment: "but if you read the memory bytes in order on a Big Endian machine, it reads as NUXI"  That's complete nonsense. The only way to screw up like you describe is if you store character pairs in 16 bit **words, not bytes**. But why would any sane person do that? And if you did, you would get NUXI on a _Little Endian_ machine. A Big Endian machine will always store the characters "UNIX" as U=lowest address, no matter if it is a char array or a uint32_t. Have you ever even worked with Big Endian machines?

Comment: @Lundin, you really haven't heard of the NUXI problem? This is known in the 1970s. Please just google "NUXI problem". And yes, I wrote C compilers for 68K, VAX-11, PA-RISC, and...

Comment: First link: "(NUXI problem) refers to the problem of transferring data between machines with differing byte-order. The string “UNIX” might look like “NUXI” on a machine with a different byte sex (e.g., when transferring data from a little-endian to a big-endian, or vice-versa).
NUXI problem - Catb.org
www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/NUXI-problem.html"

Comment: I see the potential confusion: we are probably in violent agreement. You probably think that when I used the term "stream of bytes" I meant writing the bytes one byte at a time. I should have been more precise to say "writing a stream of bytes regardless the data type used", e.g. you can write a sequence of bytes, a sequence of 16 bits, or a sequence of 32 bits (assuming the LE machine is a "pure" Little Endian machine), and the results are the same. So it is "easier to map a stream of bytes/ASCII characters into memory", as I have written.

Comment: Your "NUXI" problem is probably just the Little vs Big endian problem. But there exists no system in the world (that I know of) where ASCII characters are not stored with the first letter at the lowest address and the last letter on the highest address. And so there exist no known systems in the world that would print the ASCII string `"UNIX"` as `"NUXI"`.

Comment: @Lundin, it's not entirely academic, imagine you are writing a program for a BE machine, and you correctly write a string of ASCII characters, e.g. UNIX as bytes. Now if you run the program under a debugger, and viewing the memory as 16-bit or 32-bit WORDS (most likely the default in a memory view), you would see the content displayed as the equivalence of NUXI.

Comment: Why would you ever view the memory as words in a debugger, if that's not what's stored at that memory location, let alone what you are interested in seeing? Sounds like bad programmer using a bad debugger more than anything else. I don't think I have ever used a debugger that bad and then I have used at least 30 different ones, including some very bad ones. So which debugger are you speaking of, more precisely?

Comment: Instead of drifting off-topic, perhaps you would care to answer "Why would you ever view the memory as words in a debugger". You drag in this "NUXI problem" but you can apparently not even illustrate with an example of when it will happen.

Comment: @Lundin, it is not drifting off-topic. If you have used a debugger that shows memory as I said, and there are many more primitive ones, that's what you see. I know you want to "win". That's fine. You win. Anyone can google "NUXI problem" to know it's a real problem. If you have never encountered it, good for you.

Comment: and honestly, it's not that hard to imagine. You have multiple variables:
struct { int anarray[4]; char string[5]} x = { {1,2,3,4}, {"UNIX"}};

Then you are looking at memory view window, you are not dumping variable per se, just looking at the address (for example, a primitive debugger that does not display structure), then bam, you see NUXI on a BE machine.

Comment: No! You are looking at UNIX since a BE machine stores the data as U, N, I, X in that order. As does a LE machine. When I google "NUXI problem" I only get generic, bad explanations about the difference of BE and LE, which again, does not apply to strings. The fact that you keep insisting that byte order would be LS byte first on BE shows that you don't even understand which one that's Big Endian and which one that's Little Endian.

Comment: To spell it out to you, this example https://godbolt.org/z/IC21Vs will print the hex corresponding to "XINU" on a LE machine and hex corresponding to "UNIX" on a BE machine. In order to get NUXI, one has to do something extra-ordinarily strange like storing characters in 16 bit word sequences and then print it on a Little Endian machine.

Comment: @Lundin, the issue is that you are only considering native development. I write C cross compilers and do a lot of firmware development for different micros. It just so happen that I only have LE micros test boards currently (ARM Cortex-M and AVRs) but I used to write firmware for 68HC12 and 68HC11, BE micros. The debuggers running on PC by default display memory in LE format. The good ones lets you tick a box to switch to BE format if the target runs in BE mode, but there are a lot of ancient ones that do not. Voila, you have your NUXI right there.

Comment: All debuggers for HC12//HC08 I've used did not have any such peculiar oddities. Not Codewarrior, not IAR, not Cosmic, not Lauterbach, not PE Micro. So which debugger, exactly? And again, strings don't depend on endianess...